# Cannot integrate the function. double to sym

Tags: matlab, symbolic-integration

I'm trying to integrate the function. I'm getting the error 
`Undefined function 'int' for input arguments of type 'double'.`
Here is my code:

```
P = @(m,sigma,t,C) (normcdf((C-m/sigma)/sqrt(t),0,1) - exp(2*C*m/sigma)*normcdf((-C-m/sigma)/sqrt(t),0,1));
Pr = @(m1,m2,sigma_1, sigma_2,t,C) (P(m1,sigma_1,t,C)*P(m2,sigma_2,t,C));
P_S = @(m1,m2,sigma_1,sigma_2,C) (1 - int(Pr(m1,m2,sigma_1,sigma_2,t,C), t, 0, inf));
```

What am I doing wrong and how to integrate this function?

Answer (score 0):

`normcdf` is used for floating point calculations and does not support symbolic input. You need to write your own. Luckily that's pretty easy. Try replacing `normcdf` with this:

```
normcdf_sym = @(x,mu,sig) (1./(sig*sqrt(2*sym('pi'))))*int(exp(-(t-mu).^2./(2*sig.^2)),t,-Inf,x);
```

Or with this, which is is equivalent to the above:

```
normcdf_sym = @(x,mu,sig) (1+erf((x-mu)./(sig*sqrt(2))))/2;
```

Also, you'll likely want to define your symbolic variables as real: `syms m sigma t C real;`. Or use the [`assume`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assume.html) and [`assumeAlso`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumealso.html) functions.

All this is assuming you want to use symbolic integration in the first place, as opposed to numeric integration.

Comment: thank you very much! I'll try it. but actually I define c, sigma and m like this: `C = 0; m = 1; sigma = 0.1;`. and now it works without errors if replace `int` with `integral(@(x)Pr(m1, m2,.....))`. But then I have an another problem. I have to find the zeros of P_S function. So I should use `fzero()` or `fnzeros()`. But I get the next error: `input is of unknown(function) form` in line with `fnzeros`. What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: So you wanted to do numeric, not symbolic, integration. Note that when you type `help int` (or `help sym/int`) right away you see "...indefinite integral of S with respect to its symbolic variable...". And when you type `help integral` you see "...Numerically evaluate integral...". These are very different things and it would be a good idea to learn if you're even using the the right function before trying it. For example, right from one of the first lines of `help fnzeros`: "...an ordered list of the zeros of the univariate spline F...". Are you using splines? Likely not.

Comment: By the way, for future reference: [symbolic computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation) vs. [numeric computation (numeric analysis)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_computation).